# Getting Date only instead of date and time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, date

Ok so i have sorted the difference of Dates, it's working great. The problem i am facing now is that when i click on `date` from the Calender (AJAX calender that appears when you click on `TextBox`) It adds `Date` along with the `null time` to database. I only want `Date` not `Time`.
**Please note:** that the `DataType` of `AdmitDate` and `DischargeDate` is set to `datetime`.

Here is my C# code:

```
string str = "update Patient set Department= @Department,Ward=@Ward,Bed=@Bed,Status=@Status,AdmitDate=@AdmitDate,DischargeDate=@DischargeDate, NumOfDays=@NumOfDays   where PID = '" + TextBox3.Text + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ward", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bed", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmitDate", TextBox1.Text);
        DateTime AdmitDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        // AdmitDate.ToString("d");
        AdmitDate.ToShortDateString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DischargeDate", TextBox2.Text);
        DateTime DischargeDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
        // DischargeDate.ToString("d");
        DischargeDate.ToShortDateString();
        var diff = (DischargeDate - AdmitDate).Days;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumOfDays", diff);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

As you can see i tried 2 methods, they don't give any error but don't work the way they are supposed to. I tried some other things as well (mentioned here and on other sites) but they didn't work either. Any kind of help will be appreciated. 
**Additional Info:** I am using SQL server 2008 R2 with VS2013.

EDIT: here is my SQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patient] (
[PID]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Department]    NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Ward]          NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Bed]           NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Status]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[AdmitDate]     DATETIME       NULL,
[DischargeDate] DATETIME       NULL,
[NumOfDays]     INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK__Patient__C57755200BC6C43E] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PID] ASC)
```

i have removed the fields that are not relevant.

EDIT: my gridview code:

```
<div id="mbody"> <br />
                <div class="gview"> 
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="gview" DataKeyNames="PID" Width="613px">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="PID" HeaderText="PID" SortExpression="PID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Pname" HeaderText="Pname" SortExpression="Pname" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Ward" HeaderText="Ward" SortExpression="Ward" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Bed" HeaderText="Bed" SortExpression="Bed" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="AdmitDate" HeaderText="AdmitDate" SortExpression="AdmitDate" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DischargeDate" HeaderText="DischargeDate" SortExpression="DischargeDate" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="NumOfDays" HeaderText="NumOfDays" SortExpression="NumOfDays" />
                            </Columns>
```

```
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SMCConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PID], [Pname], [Gender], [Department], [Ward], [Bed], [Status], [AdmitDate], [DischargeDate], [NumOfDays] FROM [Patient]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Patient] WHERE [PID] = @PID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Patient] ([Pname], [Gender], [Department], [Ward], [Bed], [Status], [AdmitDate], [DischargeDate], [NumOfDays]) VALUES (@Pname, @Gender, @Department, @Ward, @Bed, @Status, @AdmitDate, @DischargeDate, @NumOfDays)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Patient] SET [Pname] = @Pname, [Gender] = @Gender, [Department] = @Department, [Ward] = @Ward, [Bed] = @Bed, [Status] = @Status, [AdmitDate] = @AdmitDate, [DischargeDate] = @DischargeDate, [NumOfDays] = @NumOfDays WHERE [PID] = @PID">
                            <DeleteParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="PID" Type="Int32" />
                            </DeleteParameters>
                            <InsertParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Pname" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Ward" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Bed" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="AdmitDate" Type="DateTime" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="DischargeDate" Type="DateTime" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="NumOfDays" Type="Int32" />
                            </InsertParameters>
                            <UpdateParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Pname" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Ward" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Bed" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="AdmitDate" Type="DateTime" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="DischargeDate" Type="DateTime" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="NumOfDays" Type="Int32" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="PID" Type="Int32" />
                            </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

            </div>
```

Comment: AdmitDate.ToShortDateString() isn't getting assigned to a variable.

Comment: Why data type is datetime instead of Date then? If you specify datetime as data type then behaviour is correct.

Comment: aaaaa let me try summin, thanks for the guideline.

Comment: @Amit i tried `date` only as well, it worked still the same.

Comment: date as sql table data type?

Comment: yes as sql data type @Amit

Comment: Can you share your SQL table structure?

Comment: @Amit i edited my question. Please see there.

Comment: @Sana - Not able to see edited part.

Comment: @Amit check again please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want to save up the only date part of the `datetime` you can do that as below:

```
    DateTime AdmitDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmitDate", AdmitDate.ToShortDateString());
    DateTime DischargeDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DischargeDate", DischargeDate.ToShortDateString());
```

In your code you are not assigning the `ToShortDateString()` value to anything that's why the changes aren't reflecting.

And you might want to change your query to use it `parametrized` values to avoid SQL injection. [Here is more info on it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

```
string str = "update Patient set Department = @Department, Ward = @Ward, Bed = @Bed, Status = @Status, AdmitDate = @AdmitDate, DischargeDate = @DischargeDate, NumOfDays = @NumOfDays where PID = @PID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", TextBox3.Text);
```

**UPDATE**

As from your comments it is clear that the date you are showing up in the UI is showing time because you need to make sure that the value is converted to to only date before setting it to the UI control.

**OR**

If you have full control of the tables and you never ever want to store time then the ultimate solution would be Change the `DateTime` to the `Date`.

In this case to when you fetch it and if you store it in the `DateTime` type variable it will add the `Time` part to it. So you have to apply the `.ToShortDateString()` before assigning it to the UI control.

**UPDATE**

TO change the UI you need to put the [DataformatString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `boundfield` of the date columns. In your gridview for these 2 lines add the `DataformatString` property with the value `{0:MM/dd/yyyy}`

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="AdmitDate" HeaderText="AdmitDate" SortExpression="AdmitDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DischargeDate" HeaderText="DischargeDate" SortExpression="DischargeDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
```

Comment: thanks,  this is what i am getting. I don't think it's being used anywhere else. [link](http://prntscr.com/694z16)

Comment: You are setting `"@AdmitDate"` multiple times. That's why the error.

Comment: still getting ok, fixed the error but this is how i am getting it still : [link](http://prntscr.com/695263)

Comment: The time is added when you are displaying the result on UI. You should check the code which are fetching the data from database and showing on UI.

Comment: @Agree to Coder of Code

Comment: ToShortDateString() is culture sensitive thus SQL Server may not convert it as you expect. Consider the date 4/5/2015 in some countries this is 5th of April but in others (like Bulgaria) it is 4th of May so in order to be exact you can do .ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");

Comment: I am showing it in `GridView`.. if it helps. They are 2 seperate gridview columns.

Comment: Ok post your gridview bind code and gridview script aspx code in question .

Comment: YOU, my friend, are the best! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only date part to be stored in DB then use datatype of column as date.

For example -

```
DECLARE @date1 date= '02-24-15 23:20:51'; -- will take only the date  
SELECT @date1 AS 'date1'
```

Will have -

```
date1
--------------
2015-02-24
```

EDIT-

From your edition and of table structure I ran simple test and it is working fine.

```
CREATE TABLE #Patient (
[PID]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Department]    NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Ward]          NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Bed]           NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Status]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[AdmitDate]     Date       NULL,
[DischargeDate] Date       NULL,
[NumOfDays]     INT            NULL
);

Insert into #Patient Values('ABC','Ward1','Bed2','Active','02-24-15 23:20:51','02-26-15 23:20:51',2);

Select * from #Patient;
```

Results-

```
PID         Department                                         Ward                                               Bed                                                Status                                             AdmitDate  DischargeDate NumOfDays
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ------------- -----------
1           ABC                                                Ward1                                              Bed2                                               Active                                             2015-02-24 2015-02-26    2
```

If you check I modified datetime data type to date

```
    [AdmitDate]     Date       NULL,
    [DischargeDate] Date       NULL,
```

Comment: Data type for structure you shared is datetime. Change it to date by altering table. Also, are you connected to right SQL Server and DB? Also, use Date.TryParseExact instead of Date.Parse.

Comment: Have you tried Date.TryParseExact? What is the format you have set for CalenderExtender?

Comment: If you put debug breakpoint on line cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdmitDate", TextBox1.Text);
What is the value you are getting for TextBox1.Text?

Comment: I tried the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method, this is what i am getting: [link](http://prntscr.com/695e4e)

Answer (score 0):

Accordimg to :

> the DataType of AdmitDate and DischargeDate is set to datetime.

you can't insert only date-part  to these column.if you tried then it'll automatically save the time as a 12:00 AM(starting time of the day).

if you really want to insert only date then change the column datatype to date.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype
```

See:[Alter_Table_datatype](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Comment: in date column value saving as a date-time??@Sana Qureshi

Comment: Then it's Magic, Enjoy It. :P

Comment: Last:
" It's still giving the Time part " what it means??
did you tried in Sql-Query window like.
"select date_colum from tbl_name"  and you got the time part too??

Answer (score 0):

DateTime AdmitDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

string admitDate = AdmitDate.Date; // it gives you only Date

If you want only Date in SQL SERVER means you need to change the datatype of the column from **datetime to date.**